# how to hide methods out of constructor from class also being returned?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i am new in classes and i have this code:

```
class BoardTypeResponse {
  created_on: string;
  name: string;
  threads: string[];
  updated_on: string;
  _id: string;
  delete_password: string;
  loading: BoardLoadingType;
  error: BoardErrorType;

  constructor(params: {
    name?: string;
    delete_password?: string;
    _id?: string;
  }) {
    this.created_on = this.now();
    this.name = params.name || 'TEST BOARD NAME';
    this.threads = [];
    this.updated_on = this.now();
    this._id = params._id || this.genUuidV1();
    this.delete_password = params.delete_password || this.genUuidV1();
    this.loading = {
      update_name: false
    };
    this.error = {
      update_name: ''
    };
  }
  private genUuidV1 = () => uuidv1();
  private now = () => new Date().toISOString();
}
```

the problem with this created object is it also includes methods genUuidV1 and now on returned object which i thought private would work:

```
{
  created_on: '2019-09-16T16:26:49.885Z',
  name: 'UPDATED CREATE BOARD TEST',
  threads: [],
  updated_on: '2019-09-16T16:26:49.885Z',
  _id: 'c8ebf4d0-d89e-11e9-81ae-1dc34f066a52',
  delete_password: 'abcd123',
  loading: [Object],
  error: [Object],
  genUuidV1: [Function],
  now: [Function]
}
```

i don't want that genUuidV1 and now seen, how do i hide it returned?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @JonasWilms i was learning classes and thought to try but i just settled with creating a constant and assigning it atm, i missed the methods being returned at first and thought maybe there's a way to hide it

Comment: Again: Why would you need that? Typescript prevents you to access these properties from the outside *at compile time*.

Comment: i want to create an object without those methods

Answer (score 1):

**Write a custom return method**

```
class BoardTypeResponse {
    created_on: string;
    name: string;
    threads: string[];
    updated_on: string;
    _id: string;
    delete_password: string;
    loading: BoardLoadingType;
    error: BoardErrorType;

    constructor(params: {
        name ? : string;
        delete_password ? : string;
        _id ? : string;
    }) {
        (this.created_on = this.now()),
        (this.name = params.name || 'TEST BOARD NAME'),
        (this.threads = []),
        (this.updated_on = this.now()),
        (this._id = params._id || this.genUuidV1()),
        (this.delete_password = params.delete_password || this.genUuidV1()),
        (this.loading = {
            update_name: false
        });
        this.error = {
            update_name: ''
        };
    }
    genUuidV1 = () => uuidv1();
    now = () => new Date().toISOString();
    getObject = () => {
        return {
            created_on: this.created_on,
            name: this.name,
            threads: this.threads,
            updated_on: this.updated_on,
            _id: this._id,
            delete_password: this.delete_password,
            loading: this.loading,
            error: this.error,
        };
    };
}
```

**usage:**

call **getObject()**

```
let obj = new BoardTypeResponse();
let y = obj.getObject();
```